# Invisible graphs

Tags: tkz-fct

my graphs are not working I don't know why. For example, here's one of them.
[image]

The code is:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',scale=1]
\tkzInit[xmin=-2,xmax=4,
         ymin=0,ymax=10,
         xstep=1,ystep=2]
\tkzAxeXY
\tkzFct[domain=-2:4,color=OliveGreen,very thick,-]{\x+4};
\draw [color=OliveGreen] (4.1,4.2) node {$r$};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\caption{\small Gráfico de $f(x)=x+4$.}
\label{fig4.8}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please, make the example compilable (but as short as possible), adding what's necessary to process the code, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: If I'm seeing this right, `tkzFct` uses `gnuplot` (via [TikZ](https://tikz.dev/tikz-plots#sec-22.6)). That means you need to have gnuplot installed (and findable by LaTeX) and say `pdflatex` needs to be called with option `--shell-escape` or `enable-write18`, depending on your TeX installation. Also, try `x` instead of `\x` (the latter is defined by `tkzFct` to use `x` but with some transformation).

Comment: why not using `\draw plot` of TikZ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a TikZ solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=.8]
\draw[violet!25] (-2.5,-.5) grid[ystep=2cm] (4.5,10.5);
\draw[-stealth] (-2.5,0)--(4.5,0) node[below]{$x$}; 
\draw[-stealth] (0,-1)--(0,10.5) node[right]{$y$};  
\definecolor{OliveGreen}{RGB}{109,113,46}
\draw[OliveGreen,very thick] plot[domain=-2:4] (\x,{\x+4});
\foreach \i in {-2,-1,1,2,3,4} 
\draw (\i,.2)--(\i,-.2) node[below,fill=white]{$\i$};
\foreach \j in {2,4,...,10} 
\draw (.2,\j)--(-.2,\j) node[left=1mm,fill=white]{$\j$};
\path 
(-2,2)--(4,8) node[OliveGreen,sloped,midway,below=1mm]{$f(x)=x+4$}
(current bounding box.south) node[below=2mm]{Gráfico de $f(x)=x+4$};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```